# Import Project to Immediate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, read-eval-print-loop

Having just installed VS2015 Update 1, I discovered the [C# Interactive window](http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/11/14/using-the-c-interactive-window-that-comes-with-roslyn/).

According to the [second](http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/11/25/using-the-c-interactive-window-that-comes-with-roslyn-part-2/) post in that series, you should be able to import a project from your solution.

> When you want to fire up the C# Interactive Window you can just right click your solution and select "Reset Interactive from Project"

However, this option is not available on my project. I'm using a Console Application to test, and have pushed the framework up to 4.6.1 from 4.5. However, this has not worked.

Additionally, I have attempted to manually import the project. Looking at the screenshots on the website, I should be able to do this like this: `#r "ConsoleApplication7.exe"` but when I do, I get the following exception:

> (1,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'ConsoleApplication7.exe' could not be found

It will pull in via the filepath, e.g:

```
#r "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe"
```

However, this is a little unwieldly. Especially since whenever you make changes to the classes, it requires a `#reset` and re-import.

Is there a better way to import Projects into the Immediate instance?

Comment: maybe you have to add the complete path to ConsoleApplication7.exe like `bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe`

Comment: @AntiHeadshot That *does* work, but its not very neat. I'll update the question.

Comment: The relative path should be enough, so just 'bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe', how should VS know where to search fo the file, it could be in debug, release or some compleatly different folder you have defined. ... ok thinking about it VS should be able to figute it out ^^

Comment: It doesn't really answer your question, but unfortunately we had to cut the "Reset from Project" command in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 just because we were crunched getting everything else done. We don't like that it's not there either.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski That essentially answers the (implied) question. Thanks for the heads up. Does that mean AntiHeadshots comment about using the path is the recommended way to do it currently?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. :-)

Comment: @AntiHeadshot If you want to create an answer with details of the solution with relative path, I'll revert that part out of the question and mark it as an answer - its probably the best we can get at the moment. Might be worth mentioning it being dropped from Jasons comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Comment from Jason Malinowski

> It doesn't really answer your question, but unfortunately we had to cut the "Reset from Project" command in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 just because we were crunched getting everything else done. We don't like that it's not there either.
>
> [Jason Malinowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972216/jason-malinowski)

Therefore, at this time (2016-02-04), the "Reset from Project" option is not available.

Projects *can* be imported manually, by using the following command:

```
#r "bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe"
```

This should work when you are running the REPL with the solution open in the same instance, and when you have only one project.

At other times, you will need to use the full file path

```
#r "C:\MySolution\ConsoleApplication7\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication7.exe"
```

Comment: If you need to recompile your dll I had to execute the *reset* command from within the Interactive window and then re-execute my *#r* reference command again.